# What does bind-address = * (asterisk) mean in mysql

Tags: mysql

I understand that the bind-address property stores the IP address (or range of IP addresses) that can connect to the mysql server, but I don't understand what the * (asterisk) value represents. Is it synonymous with 0.0.0.0 (i.e.: accept connections from all addresses)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` causes the server to listen on all addresses, IPv4 and IPv6, whereas `0.0.0.0` only causes it to listen on all IPv4 addresses.

From ["5.1.7 Server Command Options"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address):

> - `--bind-address=addr` (...)
>
>   - If the address is *, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces, and, if the server host supports IPv6, on all IPv6 interfaces. Use this address to permit both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on all server interfaces. (...)
>   - If the address is 0.0.0.0, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces. (...)

Comment: On MySQL 5.7.26 Community Edition running on CentOS 7, bind_address=* doesn't behave as described by the MySQL docs.  Instead, it listens only to ipv6, not ipv4.  I was only able to get it to listen to ipv4 by using bind_address=0.0.0.0, which unfortunately also makes it not listen to ipv6.

Answer (score 1):

`bind-address =*` means bind on IPv4 or IPv6 or both with INADDR_ANY and/or IN6ADDR_ANY.

That means any client that can connect to your system can attempt to connect to MySQL (so your security needs to be well configured in MySQL).